# How to make JQuery return View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

Before, I had my form directly call the Action, but now, I want to use JQuery to do stuff before having the Action called. The problem I have is that before, when I called return View() from the controller, it would reload the partial page with the message I put into the Viewbag.Message. How do I do that with JQuery?

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    DoStuff();
});
function DoStuff()
{
    $.ajax("Home/DoStuff"), function() {

    };
}
```

$

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff()
{
    string value = Request.Form["value"];

    Viewbag.Message = TempData["message"];

    CustomView view = new CustomView();
    return View(view);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider something like this (not tested):

```
<html>
    ...
<body>
    ...
    @Html.RenderAction("DoStuff", new { value: "" });
    ...
</body>
```

Partial View DoStuff.cshtml:

```
<div class="doStuffContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function () {
    DoStuff();
});
function DoStuff()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: @Url.Action("DoStuff"),
        data: {value: "testData"},
        success: function(result) 
            {
                $("doStuffContent").replaceWith(result);
            }});
}
</script>
<a id="button">click me</a>
@ViewBag.message
</div>
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoStuff()
{
    Viewbag.Message = "";

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(string value)
{
    Viewbag.Message = "Received " + value + "!";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I found something at this [link](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/AJAX-calls-with-jQuery-in-ASP.NET-MVC). It shows something along the lines of what you wrote. It uses a Json return to give me back the value instead of using Viewbag. I can then put that value in a div using JQuery so I don't have to depend on Viewbag.

Comment: Right, that solution is better if you just need the data. As a sidenote: If your'e working with Views/PartialViews, ViewBag is generally not the best option - use strongly typed views, that saves you from a lot headache in the long term.